As an adverb, which word’s more idiomatic: “clear” or “clearly”?
Both “clear” and “clearly” can be used as an adverb. I wonder which one’s more idiomatic in vernacular. For example, when you say


You didn’t say it clear(ly)
I couldn’t see it clear(ly)
You didn’t write it clear(ly)


which one’s more idiomatic in vernacular: “clear” or “clearly”?
The same question goes for “bad” and “badly”. When I say

This smells very bad(ly)

which word’s more idiomatic in vernacular: “bad” or “badly”?

A rotten egg smells bad, and my stuffed-up nose smells badly.

Typically, in US English "ly" and adverbs often go together.

A wet dog doesn't smell badly; it smells well, and it smells bad.  If the word after "smells" is an adverb, it tells you about the dog's sense of smell.  If it is an adjective, it tells you about the smell that emanates from the dog.  The sentence is not analogous to the ones in the first set of examples because the verbs in the first set of examples can't function to tell you about s property of the subject, whereas "smells" can.

Clearly is more common than clear as adverbs.
Grammarphobia has an extensive post on the issue, though it does not analyse specifically the phrase say something clearly/clear. I will quote the most important points here:

A sentence like “I speak clearly” is more idiomatic (that is, natural to a native speaker) than “I speak clear.” However, “I speak loud and clear” is just as idiomatic as “I speak loudly and clearly.”

The site quotes Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage that says:

Both clear and clearly are adverbs, but in recent use they do not overlap. Clear is more often used in the sense of ‘all the way.’

As an example, I will give one from the dictionary itself (not quoted by Grammarphobia), as I find it more illustrative in this sense:

My ticket from San Francisco clear to New York City (Jack Kerouac, Esquire, March 1970)

Then the post adds the OED's remark that:

“clear” is also used adverbially to mean distinctly or clearly, as in “loud and clear” and “high and clear.” The OED adds that “in such phrases as to get or keep (oneself) clear, to steer clear, go clear, stand clear, the adjective passes at length into an adverb.”

The site also quotes Fowler’s Dictionary of Modern English Usage (4th ed.), where Jeremy Butterfield says:

Clearly is overwhelmingly the more usual adverbial form of the two.

The post gives a thorough analysis of the reasons why and how clear and clearly have come to be used both as adverbs.
If you are still not convinced, this Ngram will prove that says it clearly is far more idiomatic than says it clear, though the latter does seem to slightly increase in popularity:

As for bad/badly after sense verbs such as smell, taste, feel, I think you should ask a separate question. But I will quote M-W's usage note:

There are a number of linking verbs in English, among them be, become, seem, and all of the sensory verbs: smell, look, taste, sound, and feel. And while each of these can also be used as an action verb, it's easy to tell when they're being used as linking verbs, as in these cases involving the sensory linking verbs:

Those pies smell delicious. NOT: Those pies smell deliciously.


And Grammarist warns that:

You can smell badly because you have a cold [as in your nose is blocked and can't really smell anything] or you can smell bad because you haven’t taken a shower.


OED's “in such phrases as to get or keep (oneself) clear, to steer clear, go clear, stand clear, the adjective passes at length into an adverb.” really needs supporting research. The indeterminacy of 'wide' in 'He shot wide' ('wide' an adverb here? resultative adjective?) has been mentioned before on ELU. With say 'stand clear', it could even be interpreted as a depictive construction. // Far more thorough than answers at the prior duplicate.

That Ngram looks very strange with the explosion after 2014, and the links to Google Books do not seem to justify it.

@Henry You are quite right actually, thanks for pointing it out.

What a strange difference an s makes

@Henry I know Ngrams are not always reliable and the one with SAY or SAID (!) are indeed weird. I wonder why but I am not curious enough to investigate :)

I must fess up to my down-vote here. The main reason is that clear is a depictive adjective (or PC), not an adverb. That misinformation re clear etc is what you get if you try and get part of speech information from dictionaries!

@Araucaria-Him — Are you actually saying clear is never an adverb? How about fast?

@TinfoilHat There is an adverb fast, unsurprisingly (consider *he ran fastly). But there is no adverb clear that I am aware of.

@Araucaria-Him — It is an adverb. From the OED: [Clear is not originally an adverb, and its adverbial use arose partly out of the predicative use of the adjective, as in ‘the sun shines clear’; partly out of the analogy of native English adverbs which by loss of final ‑e had become formally identical with their adjectives, esp. of clean adv., which it has largely supplanted.]

@TinfoilHat See here, please.

@TinfoilHat That's for your info, but one should really never, ever give dictionary descriptions of parts of speech for readers here. Not if you want to provide readers with serious and accurate information.

Do you actually think the OED’s note on clear as an adverb is uninformed and inaccurate?

@Araucaria-Him — And before you dis flat adverbs, see also your CGEL: “Adverb pairs of the type loud ∼ loudly ... The former are of more limited distribution than the latter, and are commonly subject to prescriptive criticism.”

@TinfoilHat Have you not read the post?

@TinfoilHat Do you have a page number for that CGEL quote, please? (Also, why  your there?)

p. 1584 (and your because CGEL is one of your sources of “proper academic grammar of English”)

@Araucaria 'The dog jumped clear over the fence.' The intensifier usage is often classed as an adverb (though I prefer the 'modifier of PP' tag I found in one article). And 'loud and clear' is used adverbially.

In my experience, there is not one way that is consistently preferable across all examples. I have never heard someone say 'this thing smells badly,' and if I were to hear it that way, would be tempted to anthropomorphize the subject, questioning the subject's level of ability to smell things. In that example, the answer is clearly 'bad'. As for 'clear/clearly', I hear and use the -ly form far more often.

Hello, Ricky. This is really a comment rather than the type of answer valued on ELU; we've all had to negotiate the 50-rep hurdle. // Look up questions here on 'flat adverbs'; sometimes, as here, flat and prototypical adverbs have different senses (eg 'We flew direct [no intermediate stops] / directly [without delay] to Tokyo'.) Then there's the 'adverb or adjective in a "secondary predication" construction?' issue.

Hi Ricky. Welcome to EL&U. That's a plus 1 from me! (I've edited out the comment to other users, but you can stick it below your post in the comments box yourself!)

Am I missing something about vernacular? Does not vernacular vary with geography? Is my nearly half century of living not qualify me to report on the vernacular of my region? I answered the question with an answer that was suited to the specifics of the question and simple to understand and therefore, helpful to the person that asked the question. I place the one asking the question above the elite masters of syntactical exactitudes when I interpret the question as answerable effectively with less. I understand my last paragraph being edited out for expanding past the focus.

Those examples seem perfect instances of the difference between US American and British English, though even that is at least as much about dialects.
In US American English 'say/see/write it clear…' might be acceptable. 'Better spoken' Americans might see that as dialectical or idiomatic; not necessarily wrong. For examples, see M.A.S.H.
In British English 'say/see/write it clear…' might conceivably be used, but only the most academic Britons would accept it as dialectical or idiomatic. 'Better spoken' Brits would see it as necessarily wrong. For examples, see Pygmalion or My Fair Lady.

But 'I hear you loud and clear' would be as is on both sides of the Atlantic [CD]. I'd agree largely though that the flat adverb is far more common in the US; perhaps the DV is for lack of actual examples (or data) with checkable references and links.

Thanks and I forgot to acknowledge that historically, British and US American, Australian, Canadian and New Zealand military signallers would certainly accept the semantics of 'I hear you loud and clear…', but it would be long ago - if ever - that any of them used such a phrase. I suggest before about 1950 and also that the date isn't the point.

I suggest you look at this Google 3-gram. Not my downvote, by the way: there certainly is a US/UK divide in the usage of flat adverbs ... but acceptability is as usual hard to determine / easy to pontificate on.

Thanks Edwin, and that reminded me of a point I, for one, have been missing, which is that 'loud and clear' surely is an idiom all to itself. Am I wrong in thinking that if we drop either term, the other by itself fails? To my ear 'I hear you loud…' or 'I hear you clear' will always be wrong in British English, but might well work in parts of US America; again, see M.A.S.H.
For 'idiomatic in vernacular', see Ricky Runyan (above).
Further, it depends on the verb. Compare 'You didn’t say it clear(ly)' and 'You didn’t make it clear(ly)'

Yes; 'loud and clear' has a different distribution than 'loud' and 'clear'. // Other threads on flat adverbs exist, and acceptability has certainly changed over time, which I'm sure has been mentioned. The US - UK differences are real ... but, as usual, there is feedback eastwards, with flat adverbs becoming more common again over here in the UK. // Note that in 'You didn’t make it clear', 'clear' is not the flat adverb but the adjective in a resultative construction.

Thanks Edwin and please excuse my ignorance but I have no idea how a 'flat adverb' differs from any other. Can you show some site explaining that?

An answer at The use of real in the following cases, though closed as a duplicate, and the Wikipedia article, give good introductions. Sadly, one link is now broken. // Edulyte is probably more thorough. // There's a section showing how the flat adverb and the corresponding regular one (where both exist) can have different meanings, in a pocket grammar, but I've sadly forgotten which one.

Ah, thanks for that
